# FOSUserBundle Symfony2 Doctrine Mapping exception: class doesn't exist (works on Windows 8.1 but not on Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml, fosuserbundle, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to implement a registration using the FOSUserBundle. I followed the tutorial at https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

I updated my database using the `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` command and all entries have been updated. But when I try to load my project in the browser I'm getting:

`MappingException: Class 'Demo\BusinessBundle\Entity\BusinessUser' does not exist`

My BusinessUser Entity:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\BusinessBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="business_users")
*/
class BusinessUser extends BaseUser
{
  /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
    protected $surname;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set surname
     *
     * @param string $surname
     * @return BusinessUser
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get surname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the `app/config.yml` file. Because when I change the entity name provided in `user_class:` I get the same error with the class name I changed it to.

That part from `config.yml`:

```
# FOSUserBundle configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Demo\BusinessBundle\Entity\BusinessUser
```

Doctrine block in `config.yml`:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

The result of running `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info`:

```
Found 3 mapped entities:
[OK]   Demo\BusinessBundle\Entity\BusinessUser
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
```

Edit 1:
I copied the same project and tried it on Windows 8.1 and it works just fine. but on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it doesn't.

Comment: can you provide your `doctrine` block from `config.yml`?

Comment: Just to be sure, there is a bug in the current installation process, where composer does not properly detect the version tag `'~2.0@dev'` when you run it directly inside the console and installs an old version. Can you check your version?

Comment: Ok I've added doctrine block.

Comment: Not sure where to check it but two latest entries in `Changelog.md` are: ### 2.0.0-alpha1 (2014-09-26) and ### 2.0.0 (2014-XX-XX). So I believe it's 2.0.

Comment: hm.. No great ideas :( Maybe clear cache?

Comment: I've cleared it many times. Sadly no success :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `auto_mapping: false`

```
# app/config/config_dev.php
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: false
        mapping:
            BusinessBundle: ~
```

or `AppBundle` instead of `BusinessBundle`

Answer (score 0):

I just lost 3 hours debugging this issue. I hope I save somebody's time. In some rare cases your composer autoloade might be playing games with you. Try to execute `composer dumpautoload`, clear your cache `/var/cache/*/` and then try again.  I had the exact same problem - the entity was with the correct namespace, it was being mapped, but symfony wasn't able to find it.